# What are requirements for allocating a TPU Pod under VM architechture?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

When allocating a TPU under TPU VM architechture, pod versions such as tpu-vm-tf-2.6.2-pod is available as TPU software version. When selecting pod as software version, and following instruction at [Run JAX code on TPU Pod Slide](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/jax-pods) `jax.device_count()` cannot find TPU.

Is selecting pod version sufficient to allocate a TPU Pod or are there additional steps/requirements? How can I select which TPU VM's to run under pod?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Jax, please use Jax images `tpu-vm-base` and `tpu-vm-v4-base` instead of Tensorflow (e.g. `tpu-vm-tf-2.12.0-pod`).

```
gcloud compute tpus tpu-vm create tpu-name \
  --zone europe-west4-a \
  --accelerator-type v2-32 \
  --version tpu-vm-base
```

Note: For Jax use the same image `--version tpu-vm-base` for both TPU VM device (v2-8, v3-8) and TPU VM pod slices (e.g. v3-32, v3-64, v2-32, etc.).

For TPU version v2 and v3 please use `--version tpu-vm-base` then [Install Jax on pod slice](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/jax-pods#install_jax_on_the_pod_slice):

```
gcloud compute tpus tpu-vm ssh tpu-name \
  --zone europe-west4-a \
  --worker=all \
  --command="pip install 'jax[tpu]>=0.2.16' -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/libtpu_releases.html"
```

details [Run JAX code on TPU Pod slices](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/jax-pods). For TPU v4 please use `tpu-vm-v4-base`, details [v4-users-guide](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/v4-users-guide#tpu-setup).

Comment: To clarify, my question is not why JAX is not detecting the GPU but it is "Would setting software version to tf-pod be sufficient for a TPU to be considered TPU Pod?". On further searching, it appears that the device is single device TPU and TPU pod will have to be separately allocated.

Comment: When allocating the TPU there is an option for selecting node vs VM architecture but there are no options for single device vs pod tpu, hence my confusion.

Comment: You use `--accelerator-type` to choose single TPU device e.g. `v2-8`, `v3-8` (TPU device with 8 cores) and v2-32`, `v3-32`, etc. for TPU pod slices.  And you use the same VM image in both cases for Jax (this is different for TF).